# Calculate frequency and rate by for individuals in large data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, frequency, rate, subset

I have a large dataframe showing the time spent in a given activity for individuals in a trial, with trials repeated over several days. Here is part of the data frame:

```
    Individual  Time    activity    trialDuration   Julian
    OY-SG   27  pr  82  161
    CY-OG   70  al  82  161
    OY-SG   17  pr  82  161
    OY-SG   10  perch   82  161
    OY-SG   27  pr  82  161
    OY-SG   18  pr  82  161
    SG-YR   16  pr  82  161
   HS-YG    52  perch   135 162
   HS-YG    19  pr  135 162
```

First, I am trying to create a second dataframe with the frequency of a given activity per individual per day (represented as Julian in the above example).
Second, I want to calculate the time spent at a given activity per individual per day as a rate. I need to tally the Time column for each individual per Julian day, and divide this summed time by the trialDuration for that given Julian day. 
I've tried using aggregate() to find the frequency of each activity per individual:  aggregate(Individual, by=list(Category=prdata$activity), FUN=sum)
but I know I'm not doing it quite right. 
I don't know the best way get organized and get at these questions and would appreciate advice from someone who understands code better than I do (which is most of you!)
Thank you very much.

For the second aggregation I am trying to sum all the time spent doing each activity for each individual on a given day and then divide that sum by the trial duration on that day. The desired outcome for the first row from the above table would look something live this :

```
    Individual  Rate         activity       Julian
    OY-SG   (27+17+27+18)/82    pr            161
```

Comment: `table` calculates frequencies

Comment: How will your desired outcome will look like? The first aggregation is quite simple, while the second one is unclear.

Comment: For the second aggregation I am trying to sum all the time spent doing each activity for each individual. The desired outcome for the first row from the above table would look something live this : 
        
        
        Individual                Rate                        activity         Julian
        OY-SG            (27+17+27+18)/82     pr                   161

Comment: @DavidArenburg how do you recommend performing the first aggregation?

Comment: See my answer below. Do you now how to install packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick `data.table` solution

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(
              ActFreq = .N,
              TimeRate = sum(Time)/trialDuration[1L]
             ),
          by = .(Individual, Julian, activity)]

#    Individual Julian activity ActFreq  TimeRate
# 1:      OY-SG    161       pr       4 1.0853659
# 2:      CY-OG    161       al       1 0.8536585
# 3:      OY-SG    161    perch       1 0.1219512
# 4:      SG-YR    161       pr       1 0.1951220
# 5:      HS-YG    162    perch       1 0.3851852
# 6:      HS-YG    162       pr       1 0.1407407
```

---

Edit per your comment, if `Time` is a factor, you probably will want to convert it to numeric class first (instead of doing it in each iteration), simply do

```
setDT(df)[, Time := as.numeric(as.character(Time))]
```

And then run the solution above

Comment: Your solution looks great! Unfortunately, when I try this with my entire dataframe I get the following error message, even after using the command as.numeric(Time):
 Error in Summary.factor(c(215L, 126L, 215L, 138L, 383L, 310L), na.rm = FALSE) : 
  ‘sum’ not meaningful for factors.

Comment: Try to replace `sum(Time)` with `sum(as.numeric(as.character(Time)))`